# What is the "best practice" when adding a user to a group using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Should I first check if a user is already a member before I try adding them to a group using the Graph API? Or should I try adding and handle assume that a failure means they already exist?

If I use the following GET request to check if the user is in the group, I get a 404 response.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{{groupId}}/members/{userId}}`

Response:

````
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource '{{groupId}}' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-10-22T07:44:27",
      "request-id": "...",
      "client-request-id": "..."
    }
  }
}```

The most likely explanation for this error is that the user doesn't exist. However I'm guessing there may also be other reasons.

If I try to add a user to a group, but they already exist, I get a 400 response:

```{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'owners'.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-10-22T07:44:56",
      "request-id": "...",
      "client-request-id": "..."
    }
  }
}```

It seems more efficient to try adding rather than first checking. Also fewer graph calls means less risk of throttling.
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting resource not found with that API means the user does not exist in that group so please try adding the user to the group using the below query.

```
POST /groups/{group-id}/members/$ref
```

please refer this document for reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http